# How to add an online bib file in latex's bibliography path?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, texmaker

Latex only lets you have a relative or an absolute path when importing a bib file, so you may have something like

```
\bibliography{../mybib}
```

Is it possible to call a url instead? For instance, something like

```
\bibliography{http://www.example.com/mybib}
```

I'm using natbib and Texmaker if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BibTeX cannot access remote files such URLs, as the short example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

shows. You get an error along the lines of

> ```
> I couldn't open database file http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/biblatex-examples.bib
> ```

---

The [Biber](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biber) back-end which replaces BibTeX if you use [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) can do that for you.

The following will work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

if you have access to the internet.

But of course you will have to switch to `biblatex` to use Biber. 
See [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864) and [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864).